# Can RSpec be configured to fail any example which does not contain any expectations?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know that in RSpec you can easily mark an example as incomplete by omitting the block:

```
it 'is not a complete example'
```

But is it possible to get RSpec to fail any example which does not contain any expectations?

IE. RSpec will happily pass this example:

```
it 'does not have any expectations but still passes' do
end
```

I want to emulate the behavior of PHPUnit which fails any test not containing any assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way, but it's a [feature I'd like to see added at some point](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/759).

In the meantime, it's not too hard to add yourself:

http://blog.sorah.jp/2012/12/17/rspec-warn-for-no-expectations

Comment: Cool, thanks for your response and your awesome work on RSpec!